# Do you need a catch block if all you're doing is throwing the caught exception?

Tags: c#, try-catch, try-catch-finally, try-finally

I found some code where they want to propagate an exception, but they want to run some clean-up code beforehand, so naturally it uses `Try`/`Catch`/`Finally`.  But... they aren't actually doing anything with the exception, only forwarding it on. It was my understanding in those cases the catch block isn't needed, but some say it actually is. I'm not sure those who do are correct.

Specifically, Microsoft's [documentation on Try-Catch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-finally) says the following...

> Within a handled exception, the associated finally block is guaranteed to be run. However, if the exception is unhandled, execution of the finally block is dependent on how the exception unwind operation is triggered. That, in turn, ***is dependent on how your computer is set up***.

What does the computer have to do with it? With the exception (no pun intended) of using `FailFast`, wouldn't a further-up try-catch block which called it properly catch this exception?  And if that's what they mean, ***man*** that was an awkward way of saying it!

Still, I think it proves the `catch{ throw; }` isn't needed, correct?

Consider the following code...

```
public static BitmapImage MakeBitmapImage(byte[] bytes){

    var ms = new MemoryStream(bytes);

    try{
        var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();

        bitmapImage.BeginInit();
            bitmapImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            bitmapImage.StreamSource = ms;
        bitmapImage.EndInit();

        return bitmapImage;
    }
    catch{
        throw;
    }
    finally{
        ms.Close();
        ms.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Couldn't it just be re-written like this (with no `catch` block) to propagate if the bitmap can't be loaded?

```
public static BitmapImage MakeBitmapImage(byte[] bytes){

    var ms = new MemoryStream(bytes);

    try{
        var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();

        bitmapImage.BeginInit();
            bitmapImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            bitmapImage.StreamSource = ms;
        bitmapImage.EndInit();

        return bitmapImage;
    }
    finally{
        ms.Close();
        ms.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Correct, that catch is doing nothing. Though that "doing nothing" might be preserved by the compiler. All it achieves is slowing down the exception hander slightly.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought. It's just an extra, unnecessary step. Mind putting that in an answer so I can close this out? (I may have to wait a day or so.  StackOverflow has a delay before accepting answers.)

Comment: Since you generally can ignore exception filters Jeremy is right... (indeed if that is a concern for your code in general that that comment is wrong)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not fully sure what the author meant, but my educated guess is that "how your computer is set up." really means "how your architecture handles unwinding." This can be different in ARM and x86.

https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/docs/design/coreclr/botr/clr-abi.md#general-unwindframe-layout

The catch block isn't needed and neither is the try block: if they're trying to guarantee cleanup they could just use a `using` statement as that will work even if there is an exception.

Comment: Actually, not quite.  `using` calls the `dispose` method but in this example, it's using a `MemoryStream` whose documentation says that although it does implement `IDisposable`, the `dispose` method doesn't actually do anything so it's not the same as calling `close`.  Granted, I'm not sure `close` even needs to be called for the same reason, but still.

Comment: The documentation is a little odd in that regard. For Close() it says "instead of calling this method, ensure the stream is properly disposed." It also says that calling Dispose() is unnecessary.

Comment: Further in the documentation on the Close method it says the following:
"This method calls Dispose, specifying true to release all resources. You do not have to specifically call the Close method. Instead, ensure that every Stream object is properly disposed. You can declare Stream objects within a using block (or Using block in Visual Basic) to ensure that the stream and all of its resources are disposed, or you can explicitly call the Dispose method."

I have no idea why they say not use Dispose and then say to use Dispose.

Comment: So I guess a using block in this case *is* preferred?!  Well, that's what I'm going to go with anyway. lol

Comment: I _think_ the documentation is trying to say because it inherits from Stream it implements IDisposable, but no clean up is actually necessary at all. Regardless, for the general case, a using block would be preferred. This documentation is so strangely confusing

Comment: Actually, I think you're spot-on there because why would you need to dispose of managed memory?  But that may not be the case for a file stream, etc.  I think we have a winner!!

Comment: Calling Close() or Dispose() is (almost) the same exact thing. Close() is the *original*, *old* method. `IDisposable` came after. So the new implementation gives a common interface (code-named V2), giving the same instruction for all, to always call Dispose(), which in turn, in this case, calls Close() on the underlying Stream. So you only need to call Dispose(), not both. Which, in turn, makes the `using` statement work for all, old and new implementations. Calling Dispose() on a MemoryStream is not strictly necessary, but you may want to *follow the lead* anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I was going to say that this is a useless noop. But after reading your linked documentation in more detail that's not quite true.

There are some situations where the runtime may terminate your process without unwinding the thread stack and running any finally blocks. Perhaps if (and only if) there is no catch handler at all. Your program is going to crash anyway, or could crash due to processing in another thread, you probably don't care about that distinction.

In dotnet core, for some kinds of failures, the runtime may call [Environment.FailFast](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.failfast?view=netcore-3.1) and just crash immediately. Though I thought this was only for failures that didn't have any call stack, like an exception that occurs while restoring the execution context. And again, other threads probably won't be unwound.

But for any finally block that is disposing managed resources, this is absolutely pointless. I'd only worry about a finally block that performed other external operations, like a file rename. And then you're going to need to test what the actual behaviour is anyway.